# How can I use one Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) to switch between multiple materials?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SkyBox : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material[] skyboxes;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < skyboxes.Length; i++)
            {
                RenderSettings.skybox = !skyboxes[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First not sure if it's good idea to use the loop.

Second getting error on the right side :

```
!skyboxes[i]
```

Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'UnityEngine.Material'

Answer (score 3):

This is a working solution :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SkyBox : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material[] skyboxes;

    private int index = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            index++;
            if (index == skyboxes.Length)
                index = 0;
            RenderSettings.skybox = skyboxes[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For wrap-around though multiple array entries in positive direction you can use `%` as a little trick:

```
public class SkyBox : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material[] skyboxes;

    private int index;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            index = (index + 1) % skyboxes.Length;

            RenderSettings.skybox = skyboxes[index];
        }
    }
}
```